# On scroll move element in DOM, later lock to top of screen

Tags: jquery, performance, scroll

I have written a little script that moves the element `.wrap` on scroll (>= 100) lower down the DOM and then sets `position:fixed; top:0;` on this moved element after it reaches the top of the page.

The result is unfortunately buggy. The element moves location and later locks to the top of the screen just fine but when you attempt to scroll back up the page the relocated element (now locked to the top of the page) flickers as you scroll <strike>also I've just realized that `.wrap` doesn't move back to it's original location when you scroll to the top of the page</strike> (Issue resolved. See comment below). I'm also concerned about performance because I'm using scroll event handlers.

Please see this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kmx4w83w/2/) for an example of the issue.

As a bonus I was attempting to add fade in/ out before the element is moved. Any help here would be appreciated.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        /*$('.wrap').fadeOut('slow');
        $.when( setTimeout(function() {  
            $('.wrap').insertAfter('.jumbotron').addClass('moved');
        }, 2000) ).then(function( ) {
            $('.wrap.moved').fadeIn('slow'); 
        });*/
        $('.wrap').insertAfter('.jumbotron').addClass('moved');
        var stickyHeader = $('.wrap.moved').offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeader) {
                $('.wrap.moved').css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0px'
                });

            } else {
                $('.wrap.moved').css({
                    position: 'static',
                    top: '0px'
                });

            }
        })
    } else {
        $('.wrap').insertBefore('.space').removeClass('moved');

    }
});
```

Comment: OK, just to add that I've fixed the issue .wrap not moving back to its original position when scrolling < 100. The issue was specific to my dev version and just a combo of the wrong class and needing to apply position: relative to `.moved`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when you attempt to scroll back up the page the relocated element (now
>   locked to the top of the page) flickers as you scroll

That is because you are continuously doing an `insertBefore` when scroll is less than 100. And also vice-versa.

To solve this, use a variable to cache the state. Wrap your logic in a condition checking the state and only then fire the code. Something like this:

```
var sticky = false;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        if (!sticky) {
            //... your logic here
            sticky = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (sticky) {
            $('.wrap').insertBefore('.space').removeClass('moved');
            sticky = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/kmx4w83w/3/

Comment: Fantastic. This is exactly what I was looking for. I've just gotta get my head around conditionals now. Thank you. I would up vote this if I had the rep.